# WordPress theme activation date

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if there is an activationdate stored somewhere. I searched for this in the database but cannot find it. I might make it through an option than but is there already something which I can use to determine on what date a theme ws activated?

Answer (score 0):

Search your WordPress DB for `theme_mods_` (in `wp_options`), there should be a timestamp (serialized) for each theme in there.

[image]